# 415 Unsupported Media Type” Error

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am having problems with getting the JSON from my form to my work with spring mvc. My form is dynamic and the JSON comes back as a object which is saved. While working with case continuously getting 415 error i.e media type not supported. Please help me and Here below is my code flow.I also tried different approaches but nothing works for me, where I did wrong?

[image]
HTML FORM

```
        <form:form modelAttribute="bp" action="saveUser" method="post" 
   name="bpForm" id="submitForm">


    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label>Name</label>
        <form:input type="text" path="bpName" name="bpName"
        class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
                            >save</button>          
    </form:form>
```

JQUERY CODE
   ###########################################################

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        data = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("ready ....");
        $('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {


            var frm = $('#submitForm');
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("submitting ....");
            var data = {}
            var Form = this;

            //Gather Data also remove undefined keys(buttons)
            $.each(this, function(i, v){
                    var input = $(v);
                data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
                delete data["undefined"];
            });
            console.log("JSON : "+JSON.stringify(data))
        $.ajax({
             headers: { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },

            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            dataType : 'json',
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(callback){
                alert("Response: Name:");
               // $(this).html("Success!");
            },
            error : function(){
              //  $(this).html("Error!");
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

######################################################################
CONTROLLER

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody BusinessPartner  submittedFromData(@RequestBody BusinessPartner user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! ==================="+user.getBpId());
    return user;
}
```

####################################

MODEL CLASS

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bp_master")
public class BusinessPartner {


@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="BPId")
private int bpId;

@Column(name="BPName")
private String bpName;



public BusinessPartner(){

}

public BpType getBpType() {
    return bpType;
}

public void setBpType(BpType bpType) {
    this.bpType = bpType;
}

public int getBpId() {
    return bpId;
}

public void setBpId(int bpId) {
    this.bpId = bpId;
}

public String getBpName() {
    return bpName;
}

public void setBpName(String bpName) {
    this.bpName = bpName;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used this maven dependency and 415 response code gone. Only duplicate  contentType : 'application/json'  removed which has been edited now.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

Now working fine on my side.

Comment: yes I have already added this one and this is working in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try to modify your method adding the `consumes` attribute and remove the `HttpServletRequest`  param :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody BusinessPartner  submittedFromData(@RequestBody BusinessPartner user) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! ==================="+user.getBpId());
    return user;
}
```

and in your form html :

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label>Name</label>
        <form:input type="text" path="bpName" name="bpName"
        class="form-control" />
       <form:input type="hidden" path="bpId" name="bpId"
        class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Or try to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded in your ajax request and catch it using MultiValueMap

```
$.ajax({
         headers: { 

                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
            },

        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        dataType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data : data ,
        success : function(callback){
            alert("Response: Name:");
           // $(this).html("Success!");
        },
        error : function(){
          //  $(this).html("Error!");
        }
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody BusinessPartner  submittedFromData(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String > data) {
 Map<String, String> params = data.toSingleValueMap();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! ==================="+params.get("bpName"));
            return user;
        }
```

Comment: hmm I think the problem is in your Jquery call your bean contains two fields but in your query you send an object with only one field

Comment: I did another example with all fields of entity class. Even that also showing same error. This one is example one ===>data : {"name":"Elecman Pty Ltd ATF ","dob":"2018-02-14","email":"pavan@srini.com.au","phone":"3434353455"}

Comment: Again getting 415 error after updated with your suggestion, Could you tell me what are the possibilities of getting this error?

Comment: there is a bad format of json in your request : "bpType.bpTypeId" not supported

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some points in your code

1. In JQuery code , you are passing contentType : 'application/json'  twice , one is inside header and other one is outside header, can remove outside contentType : 'application/json' and try it.
2. Try to use comsumes in controller for application/json or other representational data formats.